# SwiftUI - LazyVStack inside ScrollView gives unexpected behaviour

Tags: swiftui, foreach, scrollview, swiftui-foreach, lazyvstack

I'm building a chat app using SwiftUI and I'm having difficulties getting a LazyVStack to work inside a ScrollView.  Here are my questions:

**Question 1**

Where I have `.id(message.id)`, why is this id required for `scrollView.scrollTo(chatMessageViewModel.arrayOfMessages.last?.id, anchor: .bottom)` to work, when the ForEach is assigning the same id using `id: \.1.id`?  If I comment out the `.id(message.id)` line, scrollView.scrollTo doesn't work.

**Question 2:**

a) If I comment out the code `.id(message.id)`,on an iPhone 6S, I get 11 messages loaded in view, however, the print statement `print(message.messageContent)` prints out 22 messages.  Why does this happen?

b) Why are the `print(message.messageContent)` print statements not printed in order?  I thought a LazyVStack would render in vertical order?

c) As I scroll down to reveal the 12th message, I get "Message 23" printed to the console instead of "Message 12".  Why is this?

```
import SwiftUI


struct ChatMessageModel: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var messageContent: String
}



class ChatMessageViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var arrayOfMessages: [ChatMessageModel] = [ChatMessageModel(id: "1", messageContent: "Message 1"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "2", messageContent: "Message 2"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "3", messageContent: "Message 3"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "4", messageContent: "Message 4"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "5", messageContent: "Message 5"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "6", messageContent: "Message 6"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "7", messageContent: "Message 7"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "8", messageContent: "Message 8"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "9", messageContent: "Message 9"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "10", messageContent: "Message 10"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "11", messageContent: "Message 11"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "12", messageContent: "Message 12"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "13", messageContent: "Message 13"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "14", messageContent: "Message 14"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "15", messageContent: "Message 15"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "16", messageContent: "Message 16"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "17", messageContent: "Message 17"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "18", messageContent: "Message 18"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "19", messageContent: "Message 19"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "20", messageContent: "Message 20"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "21", messageContent: "Message 21"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "22", messageContent: "Message 22"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "23", messageContent: "Message 23"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "24", messageContent: "Message 24"),
                                                          ChatMessageModel(id: "25", messageContent: "Message 25")]
    
}



struct ChatMessagesView: View {
    
    @StateObject var chatMessageViewModel = ChatMessageViewModel()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
            
            ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
                
                LazyVStack (spacing: 0) {
                    
                    ForEach(Array(zip(chatMessageViewModel.arrayOfMessages.indices, chatMessageViewModel.arrayOfMessages)), id: \.1.id) { (index, message) in
                        
                        Text("Index is \(index) with message: \(message.messageContent)")
                            .padding(.vertical, 20)
                        

                            .id(message.id)
                        
                        
                            .onAppear {
                                print(message.messageContent)
                            }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                scrollView.scrollTo(chatMessageViewModel.arrayOfMessages.last?.id, anchor: .bottom)
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(chatMessageViewModel)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the intented way the LazyVStack works, it will create and destroy views as needed [LazyVStack](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyvstack), that's why the `onAppear` is called when you are scrolling, about the ordering as you can see the order is fine swiftui handles the views creation in its own cycle.

> As I scroll down to reveal the 12th message, I get "Message 23" printed to the console instead of "Message 12". Why is this?

That's because the bounce animation when you reach the bottom, the upper message will be recreated.

```
struct ChatMessagesView: View {
    
    @StateObject var chatMessageViewModel = ChatMessageViewModel()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
            
            ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
                
                LazyVStack (spacing: 0) {
                    
                    ForEach(chatMessageViewModel.arrayOfMessages.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        let message = chatMessageViewModel.arrayOfMessages[index]
                        Text("Index is \(index) with message: \(message.messageContent)")
                            .padding(.vertical, 20)
                            .id(message.id)
                            .onAppear {
                                print(message.messageContent)
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                    withAnimation{
                    scrollView.scrollTo(chatMessageViewModel.arrayOfMessages.last?.id)
                    }
               }
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(chatMessageViewModel)
    }
}
```

I would add some animation and the timeout so the scroll looks smoother.

Comment: I don't think `LazyVStack` ever "destroys" the views, it only adds more and more while scrolling – there's no reuse mechanisms as in `List`.